# I dont really understand the question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

> A series circuit with a resistor and a capacitor has a time constant of 0.25 ms. The circuit has an impedance of 350 Q at a frequency of 1250 Hz. What are the capacitance and the resistance?

I cant really pinpoint which chapter this question is in my textbook

Comment: Up to a possible $2\pi$, this can be solved with dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Since the circuit has a resistor and a capacitor, you should look at the chapter of your textbook that covers [RC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit). In particular, you will need the formula for the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) and the [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) of an RC circuit.